# Database error from Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, database

I have a page that allows registered users to post a entry on my site.

Since upgrading to the latest version of EE, I'm getting the following error, instead of the page loading:

```
Error Number: 1054
```

Unknown column 'date' in 'order clause'

SELECT DISTINCT `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id`, `exp_channel_titles`.`title` FROM (`exp_channel_titles`) WHERE `exp_channel_titles`.`channel_id` IN ('5') AND `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_date` < 1369859305 AND (exp_channel_titles.expiration_date = 0 OR exp_channel_titles.expiration_date > 1369859305) ORDER BY `date` desc

Filename: modules/safecracker/libraries/safecracker_lib.php

Line Number: 2736

Comment: I don't think it would happen. Can you check if Safecraker module files have been replaced with the latest version.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the current version (2.1) of Safecracker. And I'm getting this error every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem myself using the following bug report on the EE site:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19321

Although the bug has been fixed in more-recent versions of EE -- you can see the patches in the source files -- it still may be necessary to open and save any relationship fields in your channels.

Just go to Administration / Channel Fields, and check set set of fields for any relationship fields. Open them, don't change anything, and then update them. That solved the problem for me.